# Phonegap android to send notification to other app uers

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I have a android application which is being developed by my colleague. The app is doing task of uploading some files on to the server. My part in the app is that I have to send a notification message from a server to all or selected app users.

At server side I am using ASP.net to send a push notification to all android app users. I know I will have to use GCM. I did some research on GCM and tried some sample GCM application but what I can see is that to use GCM service the device has to be registered which is fine, but every-time I close my application the notification msg is not getting delivered and the app crashes. And has to register my device again with GCM to be able to send a notification.

How do I keep device registered with GCM untill the app is being uninstalled. How can that be achieved?

I am adding sample code I have used to achieve this:

**Server side code for sending push notification:**

```
        string regId = "APA9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPx69PQ";
        var applicationID = "AIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxU";
        var SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

        var value = "test message";
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send"); tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID)); tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
        //Data post to the Server
        string postData ="collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="+ value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() +"&registration_id=" + regId + "";
        Console.WriteLine(postData);

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();

        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        //Get response from GCM server.

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

        //Assigning GCM response to Label text
        Response.Write(sResponseFromServer);

        tReader.Close(); dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
```

**Client side code:(Phonegap)**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>PushNotificationSample</title>

    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <!-- Add stylesheets here. -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Add content here. -->
    <h1>PushNotificationSample</h1>

    <button id="register">Register for Push</button>
    <button id="unregister">Unregister from Push</button>
    <div>Status: <span id="status">not registered.</span></div>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="PushNotification.js"></script>
    <script src="https://da189i1jfloii.cloudfront.net/js/kinvey-phonegap-1.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add scripts here. -->
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/push.js"></script>
    <script>app.initialize();</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS file**

```
/**
 * Copyright 2014 Kinvey, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Push Notification namespace.
var push = {
  // The device ID. Set here because we need it in case of unregistering.
  deviceId: null,

  // Status DOM.
  status: document.getElementById('status'),

  /**
   * Initializes push functionality.
   */
  initialize: function() {

    // Check preconditions.
    if(null == window.plugins.pushNotification) {
      throw new Error('The PushPlugin is not installed.');
    }

    // Bind buttons.
    var register   = document.getElementById('register');
    var unregister = document.getElementById('unregister');
    register.addEventListener('click', push.register, false);
    unregister.addEventListener('click', push.unregister, false);
  },

  /**
   * Registers device for receiving Push Notifications.
   */
  register: function() {
    // Check preconditions.
    if(null != push.deviceId) {
      push.status.innerHTML = 'already registered.';
      return;
    }

    // Register for Android / iOS.
    var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    if('android' === device.platform.toLowerCase()) {// Android.
      pushNotification.register(push.successHandler, push.errorHandler, {
        ecb      : 'push.onNotificationGCM',
        senderID : '344215287060'// Google Project ID.
      });
    }
    else {// iOS.
      pushNotification.register(push.tokenHandler, push.errorHandler, {
        alert : 'true',
        badge : 'true',
        sound : 'true',
        ecb   : 'push.onNotificationAPN'
      });
    }
    push.status.innerHTML = 'registering…';
  },

  /**
   * General push success handler.
   */
  successHandler: function(result) {
    push.status.innerHTML = 'result: ' + result;
  },

  /**
   * General push error handler.
   */
  errorHandler: function(error) {
    push.status.innerHTML = 'error: ' + error;
  },

  /**
   * Token handler. Registers device with Kinvey.
   */
  tokenHandler: function(token) {
    push.deviceId = token;// Save.

    // Register device with Kinvey.
    Kinvey.Push.register(token).then(function() {
      push.status.innerHTML = 'registered.';
    }, push.errorHandler);
  },

  /**
   * Android notification handler.
   */
  onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
    if('registered' === e.event) {
      push.tokenHandler(e.regid);
    }
    else if('message' === e.event) {
      //navigator.notification.alert("hdgfdjf::"+e.payload.message);
      cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(10);
    }
    else if('error' === e.event) {
      push.errorHandler(e.msg);
      navigator.notification.alert(e.msg);
    }
    else {// Unknown event.
      push.status.innerHTML = e;
    }
  },

  /**
   * iOS notification handler.
   */
  onNotificationAPN: function(event) {
    if(event.alert) {
      navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
    }
    if(event.sound) {
      var snd = new Media(event.sound);
      snd.play();
    }
    if(event.badge) {
      window.plugins.pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(push.successHandler, push.errorHandler, event.badge)
    }
  },

  /**
   * Unregisters device from receiving Push Notifications.
   */
  unregister: function() {
    // Check preconditions.
    if(null == push.deviceId) {
      push.status.innerHTML = 'already unregistered.';
      return;
    }

    // Unregister.
    push.status.innerHTML = 'unregistering…';

    // Unregister device, and unregister from Kinvey.
    window.plugins.pushNotification.unregister(function() { });
    Kinvey.Push.unregister(push.deviceId).then(function() {
      push.deviceId = null;
      push.status.innerHTML = 'unregistered.';
    }, push.errorHandler);
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you developing in cordova

Comment: Yes. I am using latest version of cordova

Comment: Use push plugin this will cover all of your needs

Comment: I have updated my question please tk a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use Streethawk's Phonegap plugin for sending push messages into your application. Here is a link to detailed documentation for Streethawk.

http://api.streethawk.com/v1/docs/phonegap-introduction.html

You can also tag users (lets say admin user or normal user) using Streethawk and can manage your push messages